What is com.wingos.camerasaver?
Whenever I start my device, there is like a camera shaped indicator which shows up on the status bar for like 2 or 3 seconds. When I investigate by clicking on it, it shows that the app has no permission granted at all. I am confused as to why it keeps on happening. I can't seem to uninstall it as it doesn't appear in my "installed app section".

Looks like it's a Samsung's app. Related/possible dupe (but not answered yet): com.sec.android.app.camerasaver is using the camera in the background on Android 12

Also on Google Support: 1 (English), 2 (German) and Samsung Community (German).
